# Can not import cucumber feature files to JIRA XRAY board using the Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira, jira-xray

I am using Xray - Test Management for Jira Plugin. With the help of this plugin currently I was able to imoprt the test execution results to JIRA using the **step([$class: 'XrayImportBuilder'])**
But I am unable to import the cucumber features to JIRA using the corresponding class of the same plugin **step([$class: 'XrayImportFeatureBuilder'])**

Here is code I am using for this task,

`step([$class: 'XrayImportFeatureBuilder', folderPath: "${folderPath}", lastModified: '', projectKey: "${PROJECT_KEY}", serverInstance: "${env.XRAY_CONFIG_IG}"])`

NOTE: folderPath, PROJECT_KEY and env.XRAY_CONFIG_IG are defined before this step.

Here is the output of the above sterp...

[Jenkins Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYoSy.png)

Import Cucumber Features to JIRA Xray board using Jenkins

Comment: Are you using Cloud or Server/DC version of Jira? Make sure that in the folder path you have a .feature file or a zip file (containing multiple .feature files). Documentation for Server here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+Jenkins#IntegrationwithJenkins-Xray:CucumberFeaturesImportTask

Comment: I am using cloud version of JIRA. According to the screenshot attached you can see that plugin identifies the files inside the folder. But after it generated the zip to upload it is empty. That's the issue I am facing.

Comment: My recommendation is to reach out Xray support team (jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) so they can analyze it in more detail. Meanwhile you can try zip the feature files in a previous step and use that file in the import.